# allocating a string based on PHP if statement

Tags: if-statement

I quite new to PHP this seems to be causing me problems:

```
<?php

$ppe1="Water";

echo $ppe1; 

if ($ppe1="Tap") {
    
    $dog="time";
    
}
else

{$dog="travel";}

echo $dog; 

?>
```

I am obviously being bery stupid but I cannot seem to allocate the $dog string based on the if statement

Comment: Look up PHP `=` vs `==` vs `===`

Answer (score 0):

You should have a read on:

[Comparison Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

In short: You are not comparing but assigning a value with `=`.

```
<?PHP

$ppe1 = "Walter";

$dog = $ppe1 === "Tap" ? "time" : "travel";

echo $dog;
```

This makes use of the ternary operator which is basically `$variable = boolean expression ? then : else;`

Or with your code structure:

```
<?PHP

$ppe1 = "Walter";

$dog = "";

if($ppe1 === "Tap")
{
    $dog = "time";
}
else
{
    $dog = "travel";
}

echo $dog;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Comparison Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Use the following code. Also as you said you are a beginner, I recommend you to read [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).

```
<?php

$ppe1 = "Water";

echo $ppe1; // "Water"

if ($ppe1 == "Tap") {
    
    $dog = "time";
    
} else {
    $dog="travel";
}

echo $dog; // "travel"

?>
```

Comment: Many thanks and also for alternative scource. I had been using W3.schools but got to the end of where to go to build on ideas